# Hebrews 3:1, how to solve the confusion caused by Smith and Van Dyke translation?

Tags: hebrews, douay-rheims

The problem will be clear when we read the verse (Hebrews 3:1) in four versions, where the last phrase will be clear, as follow:

Hebrews 3:1 (Arabic- Smith and Van Dyke):

> 1. مِنْ ثَمَّ أَيُّهَا الإِخْوَةُ الْقِدِّيسُونَ، شُرَكَاءُ الدَّعْوَةِ السَّمَاوِيَّةِ، **لاَحِظُوا رَسُولَ اعْتِرَافِنَا وَرَئِيسَ كَهَنَتِهِ** الْمَسِيحَ يَسُوعَ،

Hebrews 3:1 (GNT):

> 1. ῞Οθεν, ἀδελφοὶ ἅγιοι, κλήσεως ἐπουρανίου μέτοχοι, **κατανοήσατε τὸν ἀπόστολον καὶ ἀρχιερέα τῆς ὁμολογίας ἡμῶν Χριστὸν ᾿Ιησοῦν,**

Hebrews 3:1 (Latin Vulgate):

> 1. unde fratres sancti vocationis caelestis participes considerate apostolum et pontificem confessionis nostrae **Iesum**

Hebrews 3:1 (DRB):

> Wherefore, holy brethren, partakers of [the] heavenly calling, consider the Apostle and High Priest of our confession, **Jesus,**

The phrase in bold is so confusing, the pronoun in the word "كهنته" refers to "رسولَ" or to "اعترافنا"?

- "كهنته"="his (or its) Priest."
- "رسولَ"="apostle".
- "اعترافنا"="our confession".

The Mark on "رئيسَ" (in syntactic state) refer to "رسولَ" I mean it should be "رئيسِ" to prevent any confusion.

It should be:

رسولَ اعترافِنا ورئيسِ كهنتِه

The phrase in Arabic- Smith-Van Dyke is highly confusing.

In Smith-Van Dyke it means that there are:

- a messanger of our confession.
- the high priest of this messanger.

So, translation according to Smith- Van Dyke should be:

Consider the Messanger of our confession and his (or its) high priest...

It is clear in DRB and Latin Vulgate, DRB in this verse is highly faithful to the Latin Vulgate. Latin Vulgate didn't mention "Christ" and so is DRB.

What is the Greek manuscripts, Smith Van Dyke depending upon?

I hope the problem is clear now.

I hope some Arabic scholars, who are experts in Hermeneutics, users of biblical hermeneutics stack exchange to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem isn't clear to me. "Apostle" can be "Messenger" though the first word emphasizes the person. Arabic's word for "apostle" looks like "Jesus" with a big "J"

Comment: @NigelJ I don't think we need to be so strict about that. I've definitely seen other questions before about non-English translations. But I don't know how many Arabic speaking users there are here. Unfortunately there might not be anyone who can give you an answer salah.